# How to create specified frame and send it via Bluetooth?

Tags: android, packet, android-bluetooth

I am developing an App which should send and receive packets from non-android device over bluetooth. I'm using example source code from here to manage connection and devices pairing:

[http://www.aimagin.com/learn/index.php/Interfacing_FiO_Board_and_Android_Phone_via_Bluetooth_%28Between_Andriod_and_FiO_-_Closed_Loop%29#Target_Model:Receiver_and_Sender](http://www.aimagin.com/learn/index.php/Interfacing_FiO_Board_and_Android_Phone_via_Bluetooth_%28Between_Andriod_and_FiO_-_Closed_Loop%29#Target_Model%3aReceiver_and_Sender)

Host - Android Phone
Device - My device (more less like this FiO Board from link above)

Now i want to create and send request (Step 1) from this table:

http://postimg.org/image/4n8yf27qr/

I'm doing it like this:

```
byte[] sendingbytes = new byte[6+8]; //byte array for packet

ByteBuffer buff2 = ByteBuffer.wrap(sendingbytes).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN); //wrapping byte array for modification


// Get ID, Get serial (request)
// ----------------------------------------- //
// 0xAA | 1000 0000 | 2 | 0x83; 0x84 | CRC   //
// ----------------------------------------- //
buff2.put((byte) 0xAA); //Header 0xAA
buff2.put((byte) 0x80); //flag 1000 0000

buff2.putInt((byte) 2);

buff2.put((byte) 0x83); //data 0x83
buff2.put((byte) 0x84); //data 0x84

buff2.put((byte) 0xFF); //CRC always FFFFh for testing
buff2.put((byte) 0xFF); //

if (mState == STATE_CONNECTED) mConnectedThread.write(sendingbytes);
```

My Device should respond to that request with packet like Step 2.

**My questions are:**

**1.** How to correctly create packet like Step 1,
**2.** How to decode packet (Step 2) when device send it back to me.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i figured it out. The correct packet for one command is:

```
buff2.put((byte) 0xAA); //Header 0xAA
buff2.put((byte) 0x80); //flag 1000 0000

buff2.put((byte) 0x01); //data length
buff2.put((byte) 0x00); //data length

buff2.put((byte) 0x83); //data 0x83

buff2.put((byte) 0xFF); //CRC always FFFFh for testing
buff2.put((byte) 0xFF); //
```